# Why are USB galvanic/isolators needed on battery operated devices?

Tags: usb, isolation

Why are galvanic/optical USB isolators used?

I am an astro-photographer who does imaging at remote site locations on battery.  I never encountered galvanic/optical USB isolation in devices until looking at USB relay switched power distribution boxes.

Until now I have just used a Mountain Radio Rig Runner for distribution but desire to switch my components power to OFF when the imaging session is complete to conserve battery power, and cycle dew heaters ON/OFF, on an as needed basis.  This is done using NINA, an astro-imaging Windows program. Using a 4 channel USB relay board, I built a little box to do just that, but a friend cautioned me to use USB isolation and I also noticed these were present on OEM models.

We all have various USB devices at home connected to the same PC and I don't recall USB isolators being a specification or necessary for equipment.

Could someone explain the need for these in the battery scenario vs. at home, or why, when the relay board is introduced, they are needed?

Any recommendations for a USB isolator, please provide a link.  It is a12VDC system which also provides power to board and relays.  USB power is not required for the board.  Data speed not an issue.

Cable lengths run from 2' to 9'.
Before relay board:

- camera and mount USB cable to laptop
- battery to rig runner thence 12VDC to:

  - laptop
  - mount
  - camera
  - dew controller

With relay board:

- camera and mount USB cable to laptop
- relay board USB to laptop
- battery to rig runner thence 12VDC to:

  - laptop
  - relay board operating power
  - relay board switched 12VDC power to:

    - mount
    - camera
    - dew controller

Electrical enigineering is not my wheel house.  "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing" applies to me here.

Comment: Unfortunately the devil is in the specific details of how things are interconnected and, whether the things are battery powered of powered from a mains AC supply. Generally, galvanic isolators prevent ground/earth loops causing data corruptions or, worst still; equipment failures.

Comment: I don't see why they are needed in battery operated devices. Your friend seems to know why you need one, better ask the friend. Let us know too, the reason might be a valid one or such an isolator may prove to be useless in your case. Usually you need isolators for safety, such as having a PC you use connected to some other equipment at unsafe potentials, such as live with mains voltage or 1000V or other deadly or damaging voltages that can't have galvanic connection to your PC.